# How to enable and disable button by using Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, button

Lets say, if I set a value at firebase which is ‘0’, means my button in the web page is currently disabled. If I set it to ‘1’, then the button is enabled to click. If any of you guys have done this before please share the code (both html and js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <body>

      <button id="myBtn" disabled>My Button</button>

     <p>Click the button below to find out if the button above is disabled </p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

     <p id="demo"></p>

     <script>
     function myFunction() {

      var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
     }

 </script>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible to accomplish using the Firebase Realtime Database. The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client.

You can store a value on your database, and listen for value events. Thus, you should be able to implement a JavaScript logic, which will check for that value each time the event happens. If the new value is "1", then the button will get active. If the new value is "0", then the button will become inactive.

Please check the following link for more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Is it possible to enable a button using data in firebase without click any button? Need help! Can you give me any code example for control enable/disable button using firebase data input?